# PostGIS: Merge multiple table with same GID

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0

I just imported some shapefiles with the PostGIS importer. Because several errors and issues I had to split my shapefile in multiple parts. Then I imported them one by one. I thought I can easily merge them later on.

But now there is a problem. The import tool created a primary key called GID. And these identical PKs prohibit the merge.

How do I delete these GIDS, merge all the tables and create new PKs?

Answer (score 7):

I think you can't simply eliminate GID and create a new one, as it will break the PK indexes.

To make sure you end up with a well build table I would do the following:

Create a new table based in any of the original tables. (If you are using pgadmin, you can use the create statement of the original table and give it a new name). After the table created and assuming that that all you tables have the same columns structure, I think you can use [INSERT INTO](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-insert.html) and [UNION ALL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-select.html) to try the following:

```
INSERT INTO new_table (column1, column2, column3)
SELECT
    f.column1, f.column2, f.column3
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM table1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT * FROM table2
     UNION ALL
     SELECT * FROM table3) as f;
```

Notice that columns 1, 2 and 3 represent all the tables columns except the GID, which will be populated automatically.